# I made a code for my Gif of a bird to fly across the screen but the image isn't visible even though its in the same folder

Tags: javascript, gif

Hi so I'm trying to learn how to cross a gif image across a part of my screen and the code works besides the fact that it doesnt show the image of my bird instead just a black box with an x in it and the words "Image of a bird". How ever my image is also in the same folder as my code. Any ideas where I'm wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <title>Project 12</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;
 charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js_styles.css" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
 /* <![CDATA[ */
 var topPosition = 150;
 var leftPosition = 0;
 function flyBird() {
var bird = document.getElementById("bird");
bird.style.left = leftPosition + "px";
bird.style.top = topPosition + "px";
bird.style.visibility = "visible";
topPosition -= 3;
leftPosition += 10;
if (topPosition <= 0) {
    topPosition = 150;
    leftPosition = 0;
    }
 }
  /* ]]> */
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="setInterval('flyBird()', 100);">
 <p>
 <img src="../bird.gif" id="bird" style="position:
 absolute; left: 500px; top: 281px; visibility:hidden" alt="Image of a bird" height="120"         width="150" /></p>
 <h1>Bird</h1>

 <blockquote><p>.</p></blockquote>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> my image is also in the same folder as my code

Then why are you looking for it in the parent folder?:

```
<img src="../bird.gif" ...
```

If the image is in the same folder, reference it there:

```
<img src="bird.gif" ...
```

Comment: There we go Thank you very much David. My image now appears.

Comment: You look new.  If this solved your question you should mark it with the check mark right below up/down vote buttons on the left.

Comment: Yes i was looking for something like that, It says wait 7 minutes. I'll do it as soon as time is up. @CarlosBribiescas

Answer (score 0):

If the image is in the same folder, then this

```
<img src="../bird.gif"
```

should be

```
<img src="bird.gif"
```

Comment: Elliot Thank you for your help my bird now displays itself. Appreciate it. Cheers.